# Perl printf issue

Tags: perl, printf

How do I print this example output using printf?

```
******************************************************************************
**  XYZ Corporation                   Date: March 27, 1989(Use current date)**
**  999 John Doe street                                                     **
**  Ypsilanti, MI. 48197.                                                   **
**                                                                          **
**  Pay to the order of:  ?                                                 **
**             The amount of: ?     dollars, and    ?    cents              **
**                                                                          **
**                                 signed:                                  **
**                                         President, XYZ Corporation.      **
**                                                                          **
**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**                          SUMMARY                                         **
**  Social security number:   ?                                             **
**  Regular pay:              ?                                             **
**  Overtime pay:             ?                                             **
**  Gross pay:                ?                                             **
**  Federal tax:              ?                                             **
**  Social sec. deduction:    ?                                             **
**  City tax:                 ?                                             **
**  Union dues:               ?                                             **
**  Net pay:                  ?                                             **
**                                                                          **
******************************************************************************
```

I tried my way, but I am not sure if I am right:

```
printf"
XYZ Corporation                   Date: 
999 John Doe street                                                     
Ypsilanti, MI. 48197                                                   

  Pay to the order of:  |                                                 
  The amount of: |     dollars, and    |    cents              

                                 signed:                                  
                                         President, XYZ Corporation.      

--------------------------------------------------------------------------
                          SUMMARY                                         
  Social security number:   $ssn                                           
  Regular pay:              %-.2f
  Overtime pay:             %-.2f
  Gross pay:                %-.2f
  Federal tax:              %-.2f
  Social sec. deduction:    %-.2f
  City tax:                 %-.2f
  Union dues:               %-.2f
  Net pay:                  %-.2f\n", $regPay, $overPay, $grossPay, $fedTax, $ssnDeduction, $cityTax, $unionDues, $netPay;
```

Can anyone help me? I'm sure I turned in my assignment incorrect, but I just want to know the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you should use printf here. This seems like a perfect application for Perl's `format` capabilities. These have been in the language since its inception and are why Perl is supposedly an acronym for "Practical Extraction and Reporting Language". I have never used formats, but you can learn more at this tutorial: http://www.webreference.com/programming/perl/format/index.html

To the best of my knowledge, this is a feature that has changed *very little* over the last two decades, so just about anything you find on the web should give you useful help.

Comment: I heard [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) (Perl6-style forms for Perl5) is way better than Perl5's builtin formats. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

- You didn't provide values for most of the fields.
- You removed the box of stars.
- You interpolated values into the pattern.
- You added a blank line to the top of the form.

Solution:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

my $date = strftime("%B %d, %Y", localtime);

# Doing it this way prevents floating point rounding errors.
my $net_pay_x100    = sprintf("%.0f", $net_pay * 100);
my $net_pay_cents   = $net_pay_x100 % 100;
my $net_pay_dollars = ( $net_pay_x100 - $net_pay_cents ) / 100;

printf(<<'__EOI__',
******************************************************************************
**  XYZ Corporation                   Date: %-31s **
**  999 John Doe street                                                     **
**  Ypsilanti, MI. 48197.                                                   **
**                                                                          **
**  Pay to the order of: %-50s **
**             The amount of: %5d dollars, and %02d cents                   **
**                                                                          **
**                                 signed:                                  **
**                                         President, XYZ Corporation.      **
**                                                                          **
**--------------------------------------------------------------------------**
**                          SUMMARY                                         **
**  Social security number: %11s                                     **
**  Regular pay:            %7.2f                                         **
**  Overtime pay:           %7.2f                                         **
**  Gross pay:              %7.2f                                         **
**  Federal tax:            %7.2f                                         **
**  Social sec. deduction:  %7.2f                                         **
**  City tax:               %7.2f                                         **
**  Union dues:             %7.2f                                         **
**  Net pay:                %7.2f                                         **
**                                                                          **
******************************************************************************
__EOI__
   $date,
   $name,
   $net_pay_dollars,
   $net_pay_cents,
   $ssn,
   $reg_pay,
   $over_pay,
   $gross_pay,
   $fed_tax,
   $ssn_deduction,
   $city_tax,
   $union_dues,
   $net_pay,
);
```